# How to Access Variable Outside of Return in a Child from Parent?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

If I keep my buttons in my child, this works great except for the fact I have buttons showing in every row. I'd like to move my buttons to the parent so that they just display once at the bottom of the screen. I'v tried moving my buttons to the return on the parent and putting my state code above the return. I think this would work except that my "count" value in my child, for my graphql variable "offset", now needs access to the "count" in my parent. Not sure how to make this happen. I'm pretty new to react and graphql.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import {Table, Spinner, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

const Customer_List = gql`
query getCust ($configID: Int, $first: Int, $offset: Int ) {

docsconfig (configID:$configID first:$first offset:$offset) {
  SubDomain
  ConfigID
  CustID
  customers {
    FirstName
    LastName
  }

}

}
`

function CustomerList() {

  const { loading, error, data} = useQuery(Customer_List, {
  variables: {
    configID: 1436,
    first: 10,
    offset: count
  },
}
);


  if (loading) return <td> <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
  <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</Spinner> </td>
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return data.docsconfig.map(({ CustID, SubDomain, customers, FirstName, LastName}) => (


        <tr key={CustID}>
          <td>{customers.FirstName}</td>
          <td>{customers.LastName}</td>
          <td>{SubDomain}</td>
        </tr>

    )

  )

}


function Customers () {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  function increase() {
    setCount(count + 10);
  }

  function decrease() {
    setCount(count - 10);

    if (count === 0) {
      setCount(count + 0);

    }
  }

    return (
      <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead >
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>SubDomain</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <CustomerList />
      </tbody>
      <tr>
      <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
      <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
      </tr>
       </Table>
    );
  }

export default Customers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `count` as a prop to `CustomerList`.

CustomerList

```
function CustomerList({ count }) { // <-- desctructure count from props
  const { loading, error, data} = useQuery(
    Customer_List,
    {
      variables: {
        configID: 1436,
        first: 10,
        offset: count // <-- pass to config/options
      },
    }
  );
  ...
```

Customers

```
function Customers () {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  ...

  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead >
        ...
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <CustomerList count={count} /> // <-- pass count to CustomerList
      </tbody>
      <tr>
        <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
        <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
      </tr>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It is now working! I spent so many hours trying to access that value. Looks like I need to spend some more time understanding props. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @montman Great! IMO the react docs are very good at explaining most aspects of React, and certainly how to work with state and props. Welcome to React and welcome to SO. Cheers.